# Fullcalendar V4 reload events. removeEventSource doesn't exist

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to add a calendar on my site but I don't know how could be possible to reload events from an ajax source. On previous versions you can remove the event source, add the nwe one and redraw the calendar, but in this version, I read in the documentation that it only have the `addEventSource` event.

I have a non good solution deestroying the calendar before drawing if exists, but I lose the view and day shown. Is not a good solution.

Here is my code:

```
var calendar;
var startDateSelected;  //YYY-MM-DD
var endDateSelected;    //YYY-MM-DD
var evTittleSelected;

//Example data
function getCalendarEvents() {
    return [{
        title: 'example1',
        start: '2019-07-15 12:00:00'
    }, {
        title: 'Example2',
        start: '2019-07-06 12:00:00',
        end: '2019-07-10 18:00:00'
    }];
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    drawCalendar();
});

function drawCalendar() {
    var events = getCalendarEvents();
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    if(calendar != undefined) calendar.destroy();
    calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
        locale: 'es',
        selectable: true,
        editable: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        select: function (info) {
            startDateSelected = moment(info.startStr).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
            endDateSelected = moment(info.endStr).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
            alert('de ' + startDateSelected + ' a ' + endDateSelected);
        },
        eventClick: function(info) {
            evTittleSelected = info.event.title;
            startDateSelected =  moment(info.event.start).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
            endDateSelected =  moment(info.event.end).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
            alert('de ' + startDateSelected + ' a ' + endDateSelected);
        },
        events: events
    });
    calendar.render();
}
```

I tried to changing event source like this:

```
calendar.destroy();
calendar.addEventSource( events );
calendar.refetchEvents();
calendar.render();
```

but without an `removeEventSource` method it only adds new events to the calendar.

so are there any method to reload events?

**New content** for imptove the answer (and use the solution in comments):

I tried to implement the event feed as per either 
fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed or 
fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

when I put directly events received from an ajax call to my nodejs server, it loads perfect all of them (without good option to reload). So the format of my events object seems to be ok.

I use this ajax request

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/calendar/getCalendarEvents',
    data: {
        token: localStorage.token
    },
}).then(function success(events) {
    return events;
}, function error(err) {
    console.log(err);
})
```

to fill events in this format

```
events:  [{ 
    id: 1,
    title: 'others',
    start: '2019-07-12 00:00:00',
    end: '2019-07-15 00:00:00',
    color: '#a6a6a6' 
}, { 
    id: 2,
    title: 'any',
    start: '2019-07-12 00:00:00',
    end: '2019-07-15 00:00:00',
    color: '#4222C3'
}]
```

when I try to use the `events-function` I'm having an error:  `callback is not a function error`

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/calendar/getCalendarEvents',
        data: {
            token: localStorage.token
        },
        success: function(events) {
            callback(events);
        }
    });
}
```

Using the metod events-json-feed I have the error `Failure parsing JSON` but the format is the same of the first method (that works).

```
events: "/calendar/main/?token=" + localStorage.token
```

so what could I doing wrong?

Comment: to remove an event source you must first get the event source, and then you can run the [remove](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/EventSource-remove) method against the source itself

Comment: But anyway if you want a dynamic source of events being fetched from the server automatically whenever new events are required (and easily refetchable on-demand), it's probably simpler just to implement your event feed as per either https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function (depending on how complex it is to make the call to your server)

Comment: Lots of thanks. It works with your first method. I tried it before but without getting the idea of that it is an array. Your second option it seems to be better, but I don't understand how does it works. I'm using nodejs and with the 'events-function' it seems to have problems with async, because it doesn't shows the correspondant events. probably a problem about sintax I have to invetigate. Thanks again

Comment: If you need some help with it you could always show us that code :-)

Comment: thanks I have just updated the question with the new info an code examples

Comment: You seem to have defined your function against the fullCalendar version 3 way of doing it. Check the link I gave you above (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) contains the latest documentation. You'll see the signature is different

Comment: yes that works I found an old sintax ok lots of thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ADyson comments this works fine with this solution:

```
var eventSources = calendar.getEventSources();
eventSources[0].remove();
calendar.addEventSource(events);
calendar.refetchEvents();
```

the idea is to know that `eventSources` is an array

but could be better using those methods:
[fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) or
[fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function)

```
events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/calendar/getCalendarEvents',
        data: {
            token: localStorage.token
        },
        success: function(events) {
            successCallback(events);
        }
    });
}
```

reloading events with: `calendar.refetchEvents();`